# Static file serving only works if root is a subfolder under public

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to serve static cache files using nginx. There are index.html files under the `rails_root/public/cache` directory. I tried the following configuration first, which doesn't work:

```
root <%= current_path %>/public;
try_files /cache$uri/index.html /cache$uri.html @rails;
```

This give error:

```
[error] 4056#0: *13503414 directory index of "(...)current/public/" is forbidden, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
```

I then tried

```
root <%= current_path %>/public/cache;
try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html @rails;
```

And to my surprise this works. Why is it that I can do the latter not the former( since they point to the same location)

#### Permissions of file system

The permissions of the folders are:

```
775 public
  755 cache
    644 index.html
```

Rails sits in the user `~` directory, so the folders and files are all belong to the user `good`. The user for nginx is `root` for master and `http` for each worker processors:

```
89:http      7865  0.1  0.0   8876  2624 ?        S    Jul10   0:51 nginx: worker process                        
112:root     24927  0.0  0.0   8532  1828 ?        Ss   Jun28   0:03 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

My favicon is sitting under public/ is served correctly by the following:

```
# asset server
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name assets.<%= server_name %>;
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
  charset utf-8;
  root   <%= current_path %>/public;
}
```

#### LOG

For my working setup: access log shows:

```
request:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 uri:"/index.html"
request:"GET /assets/gas/468x15_4.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 uri:"/assets/gas/468x15_4.gif"
```

If I add `index nonexistent` the same directory index forbidden error would appear with following access log:

```
request:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 uri:"/"
```

error log:

```
directory index of "RAILS_ROOT/current/public/cache/gas/" is forbidden, client: _IP_, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "gas.example.com"
```

#### UPDATE

Please see the [full config file](https://gist.github.com/3245632). Note that it is complete and the example given above are a bit simplified.

I am using Nginx 1.22

Comment: Could you show your full config?

Comment: why do you have your location blocks outside you server block?

Comment: my bad... I copy and pasted these, they are in the server block

Comment: @VBart sorry for being late, I have put full config on gist

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce. Both variants of configuration are work fine.

Comment: But you should [avoid to use if](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls) and to put `break` in every location. `break` in locations without any rewrite directives is just a noop that wasting your CPU. Why did you put breaks everywhere?

Comment: @VBart is right here, instead of big hunk of if's you can use map.

Comment: @VBart yeah would you like to write an answer. I'll accept it and merge it with mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the `if` directives in `location` blocks. These were only shown in the full config files (sorry to those who tried to solve this problem without that). Once I moved those to `server` block level it works fine.

`directory index of *** is forbidden` is an indication that no content directives are available in the location block. In this case the `location` is a **nested** `location` block, created when `if` directive is used in a `location` block.

`if` directives under `server` block level doesn't have this problem. My `if`s can be moved and still function properly, but I am not sure what `if`s won't work if moved.

So in this case file permissions are probably not so relevant.

@Vbart is correct in saying that [if is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil).

Answer (score 0):

I think [index](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpIndexModule) should be processed before try_files near NGX_HTTP_ACCESS_PHASE for as the log suggests you are requesting directory.

The correct way would be hitting official mailing list with this question.

Comment: For my working code, adding your line will cause the same directory index forbidden error. I'll post the access.log above.

Comment: Just that by reading http://www.nginxguts.com/2011/01/phases/ try_files directive is executed before content phase (index directive), so I thought index directive would never ran in my setup.